# Trying to filter out A-Z and special characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import re
string = open('old.txt').read()
new_str = re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '', string)

characters_to_remove = '!-+'
for character in characters_to_remove:
    new_str = new_str(character, '')
open('new.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

It doesn't work, can you explain why?

Comment: And? Does it work? If, not why?

Comment: Hi. Add some description about your question, please.

Comment: You will get better results here if you use an actual string you are starting with and show the expected result. We obviously can't open and read your files. Otherwise we are left to look at your code, which presumably doesn't work, to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up a text file of proxy servers formatted like
123.234.56.140:8888 HK-H-S +

I don't want the letters +,!, or -'s

Comment: @gwenavirre Why not search for the pattern of the IP Address and Port rather than searching for the letters and removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work.

This code will check with `is_alpha` if the `i` character is an alphabetic letter (A-Z, case unsensitive) and if it returns false, will add it to the `new_string` variable.
Later, it will check if the string contains the characters to remove.

```
string = open('old.txt').read()
characters_to_remove = '!-+'

new_str = ''.join(i for i in string if not i.isalpha())
for c in characters_to_remove:
    new_str = new_str.replace(c, "")


open('new.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

Check information for [is_alpha](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalpha.asp).

Comment: works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to remove every character except:

- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
- .
- :

Here you go:

```
import re

with open(r'old.txt','r') as oldFile,open(r'new.txt', 'w') as newFile:
    newFile.write(re.sub("[^0-9.:\n]+","",oldFile.read()))
```

Comment: That code does work, however a new problem is created.  All of the addresses are now jumbled together with no line break in between them.

Comment: Hello, I've added \n to the set, can you try again?